# Photoshop: update copies of background layer when background layer changed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

In Photoshop, the background layer is filled up with a picture. This layer is duplicated and various filters are applied on the duplicate. Now, I would like to change the picture in the background layer and I would like to see the duplicated layer be updated as well, with the new picture. Is this achievable?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow completely, but it sounds like what you want is [Smart Object](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html).

Comment: @Joonas you might be right yes. I will investigate. In photoshop, can the background layer be a smart object?

Comment: @Joonas You might want to provide an answer saying that the background layer should first be turned into a smart object. Then, the content of the background layer can be changed (and more importantly propagated to the duplicates) by going to Layer -> Smart Objects -> Replace Contents. Thanks

Comment: I feel you should make the answer. I only pushed you to the right direction anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The background layer should first be turned into a smart object. Then, the content of the background layer can be changed (and more importantly propagated to the duplicates) by going to `Layer -> Smart Objects -> Replace Contents`. This technique might be useful when you have a complicated set of duplicate layers with associated effects and you quickly want to see how they affect pictures other than the one you used to create your set-up.

[image]